# How to Iterate through a SortedSet of Map.Entry

Tags: java, loops, set, treeset

I have a data structures asgn I am working on.  In it, we were required to create a HashMap of word objects (Word is a custom class). Where the key is a String, and the value is a custom Word object.  From the HashMap I am required to create a treeMap that will sort the Word objects based on custom Word comparators I created.  Thus far I have been able to sort the HashMap by creating the following Method which returns a SortedSet of Map.Entry:

```
public static SortedSet<Map.Entry<String , Word>> entriesSortedByValues
(Map<String , Word> map , Comparator<Word> comp){
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<String , Word>> sortedEntries = new 
    TreeSet<Map.Entry<String , Word>>(
    new Comparator<Map.Entry<String , Word>>() 
    {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String , Word> e1, Map.Entry<String , Word> e2)
        {
            int c = comp.compare(e1.getValue() , e2.getValue());
            return c;
        }
    });
    sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
    return sortedEntries;
}
```

This works well, and returns the set ordered appropriately. However I now want to iterate over it to print the Word objects. Like so:

```
SortedSet t_set1 = entriesSortedByValues(h_Map , Word.alpha);

// this works^^ (returns correctly ordered set of Map.Entry<String , Word>)

for (Map.Entry<String , Word> entry : t_set_1)
{
    System.out.println(///WORD OBJECT)
}
```

I have tried to run for loops over it, for each, and creater an iterator.  I keep getting Incompatible Type Errors, or Entry has private access errors.  This is probably a simple fix, but I have been banging my head against the wall trying everything to get it to work. PLZ HELP :(

Comment: what is the problem you are facing

Comment: You have to define your sorted set as `SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Word>> t_set1`. Then, you are already iterating correctly with `for (Map.Entry<String , Word> entry : t_set_1)`. Then, inside the for loop do: `System.out.println(entry.getValue());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the generic type of the `SortedSet` variable:

```
SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Word>> t_set1 = entriesSortedByValues(h_Map , Word.alpha);
```

This is caused by generics being implemented with [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to maintain backwards compatibility with Java 1.4. By not adding the generic type you are effectively creating a `SortedSet<Object>`.